# Save PDF from InputStream

Tags: android

I have a problem with my code. I'm trying to save a PDF from an url. The PDF is there but its length is zero. The inputstream-length is correct though. Why ain't the PDF getting saved correctly?

This is the actual code for saving the PDF from the stream:

```
    public void createExternalStoragePrivateFile
                            (String name, String extension, InputStream is) {
    // Create a path where we will place our private file on external
    // storage.
    File file = new File
                     (mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null), name +"."+extension);

    try {
        Log.d("", "before: " + file.getPath() + 
                             " " + file.getTotalSpace() + "  " + file.length());
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];
        is.read(data);
        os.write(data);
        is.close();
        os.close();

        Log.d("","after: " + file.getPath() + 
                              " " + file.getTotalSpace() + "  " + file.length());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Unable to create file, likely because external storage is
        // not currently mounted.
        Log.w("ExternalStorage", "Error writing " + file, e);
    }
```

the output gives me this (the length is zero before and after, but the total space is not zero after. Why is the length zero?

```
04-25 09:38:44.938: D/(4103): before: /storage/emulated/0/Android
                                  /data/what.to.use.myapp/files/Lolpdf.pdf 0  0

04-25 09:38:44.946: D/(4103): after: /storage/emulated/0/Android
                        /data/what.to.use.myapp/files/Lolpdf.pdf 14311309312  0
```

Answer (score 2):

The `InputStream.available()` method will not necessarily return the size of the file being downloaded, it will return what is available without making any network calls, so is likely to be returning 0. A better approach would be to allocate a small buffer, and keep reading until you reach the end:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int len;
while ((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    os.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
```

This will be much more memory efficient as it does not require you to allocate enough memory to hold the entire document that you're downloading, and it avoids the `available()` method which is not returning what you're expecting it to.

Comment: +1 avaialble() should not be used in determining the length of the file